# Java - Matcher throws IllegalStateException after accessing group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write simple command parser class for my project. Here's what I have:

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CmdParser p = new CmdParser(args);
    String st = p.getSourceType();
}
```

CmdParser.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class CmdParser {

    private String[] args;

    public CmdParser(String[] args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    public String getSourceType() throws ParseException {
        ArrayList<String> sourceTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("--source-type=([^\\s]+)");
        for (String s : args) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.groupCount() == 1) {
                sourceTypes.add(m.group(1)); //line 28
            }
        }
        return sourceTypes.get(0);
    }
}
```

Running this with `java Main --source-type=test` causes the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at CmdParser.getSourceType(CmdParser.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I commented line 28 above. How is that possible that even though groupCount is 1, so that should be a correct group index, java throws IllegalStateException in this case? Also, why is pattern not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
if (m.find() && m.groupCount() == 1) {
    sourceTypes.add(m.group(1)); //line 28
}
```

i.e. call `find` or `matches` before `group()` method.

Comment: But that raises the question, why the pattern is not found, even though "test" should be in group 1.

Comment: @qiubit because without calling `find()` it did not yet search for it.

Comment: Yes, you have to call `find()` or `matches()`, but why are you still calling `groupCount()`?  It obviously doesn't hurt anything, but it's pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `m.find()` before `m.group()`:

```
for (String s : args) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            sourceTypes.add(m.group(1)); //line 28
        }
    }
```